# Python: Import multiple dataframes using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code which works to import a dataframe.

```
#read tblA
tbl = 'a'
cols = 'imp_a'
usecols = dfDD[dfDD[cols].notnull()][cols].values.tolist()
dfa = getdf(tbl, dfRT, sfsession)
dfa = dfa[usecols]

#read tblB
tbl = 'b'
cols = 'imp_sb'
usecols = dfDD[dfDD[cols].notnull()][cols].values.tolist()
dfb = getdf(tbl, dfRT, sfsession)
dfb = dfb[usecols]

#importing a few more tables in the steps as above two...
```

Is there a way to shorten this code and avoiding writing the same thing multiple times. The values that change are tbl, cols, dataframe name (df..)

I tried a few different things including putting all the changing attributes into a dictionary, but wasn't able to make it work. I could create a function, but the function would require a few more parameters - dfDD, dfRT, sfsession. I don't think it's a great solution. There has to be a better way to write this.

Comment: You could define a `dict` object as - ```config = {'tblA': {'tbl': 'a', 'cols': 'imp_a'}, 'tblB': {etc..}}``` and then loop through this `dict`, save your dataframes as an array of dataframes rather than having separate variables.

Comment: @CavinDsouza can you show me how to write the loop? I tried a lot of different ways but they didn't work. I'd done config = {'tblA': {'tbl': 'a', 'cols': 'imp_a', 'data': None}, 'tblB': {etc..}} and then tried to write the dataframe into data. But it didn't work.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The loop should be fairly simple like this -

```
import pandas as pd
```

Create a dictionary that will store your dataframes.

```
df_dict = {}
```

```
config = {'tblA': {'tbl': 'a', 'cols': 'imp_a'},
          'tblB': {'tbl': 'b', 'cols': 'imp_sb'}}

# Loop through the config
for key, val in config.items():
    tbl = val['tbl']
    cols = val['cols']
    usecols = dfDD[dfDD[cols].notnull()][cols].values.tolist()
    df = getdf(tbl, dfRT, sfsession)[usecols]
    df_dict [key] = df # Store your dataframe in the dictionary
    print(f"Created dataframe for table - {key} ({tbl} | {cols})")
```

Comment: thanks this worked. The thing I missed was to write the dataframe into a dictionary different from confic. I also like how you also combined the usecols step with the dataframe creation line. Is there a way now to extract the dataframes from the dictionary? I'm getting tired of typing `df_dict['tblA'] = pd.merge(df_dict['tblA'],df_dict['tblB'], .....` when preparing the dataframes.  Would be good to just write `tblA = pd.merge(tblA, tblB,...`

Comment: is your end goal to concat all the individual dataframes to make one giant datafarme?

Comment: No. I want to match projects in df1 with those in df2. But the matching fields come from df3 and df4. So import all 4, merge df1 and df3, df2 and df4; clean data; then look for matches.